# Como fazer crud com php usando JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel, crud

Estou fazendo um projeto em que vou precisar fazer um CRUD usando o JSON como armazenamento de dados. Já estou conseguindo Visualizar os dados e inseri-los. Como eu posso fazer o edit e o delete? nao tenho ideia. Sou novato nao sei como faço isso. Vou deixar um exemplo de como esta o meu Json pra vcs verem oque poderia ser feito.

**JSON:**

```
[{"codigo":"4336","nome":"teste1","email":"email1@gmail.com","telefone":"32132132"},{"codigo":"4248","nome":"teste2","email":"email2@gmail.com","telefone":"321321231"}]
```

Eu já tenho a listagem dos dados e ja tenho a pagina de editar Feita, nela terao os campos do formulário já preenchidos com a informação dos dados do xml. Estou passando o codigo(que é único), via get, pra assim tentar pegar os dados, entao a url esta assim:

> http://localhost/MeuProjeto/edit.php?id=4336

Mas não sei como trazer os dados para os campos e fazer o edit, nem sei como faço pra exclui-los também, caso o usuário deseje.

print da tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT 1:** 
Já consegui fazer com que o valor apareça nos campos, mas eu ainda nao sei como faço o edit e o delete. Me ajudem por favor.

**EDIT 2:**
Meu codigo do arquivo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Editar Colaborador - TEKNISA</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="imagens/logo.png" width="230"></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-end" style="flex-grow: 0" id="navbarText">
          <span class="navbar-text">
            Editar colaboradores
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card text-center mt-5">
        <div class="card-header">
          Editar
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        <form action="editar_colaborador.php" method="post">
            <div class="row">
              <?php 
                if(file_exists("bd/colaboradores.json")){
                  $arquivo = file_get_contents('bd/colaboradores.json');
                  $json = json_decode($arquivo);

                  foreach($json as $registro):
                    if($registro->codigo == $_GET['id']){
                      echo "<div class='col'>";
                      echo "<input type='text' name='nome' id='nome' class='form-control' required placeholder='Nome' value='" . $registro->nome . "' >";
                      echo "</div>";

                      echo "<div class='col'>";
                      echo "<input type='text' name='email' id='email' class='form-control' required placeholder='E-mail' value='" . $registro->email . "' >";
                      echo "</div>";

                      echo "<div class='col'>";
                      echo "<input type='text' name='telefone' id='telefone' class='form-control' required placeholder='Telefone' value='" . $registro->telefone . "' >";
                      echo "</div>";
                    }
                  endforeach;
                }
              ?>
            </div>

            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</a>
            <button type="submit" name="editar" class="btn btn-success">CONFIRMAR</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3:**

Eu estava com essa linha de raciocinio(está errado, é so pra vcs completarem, caso eu esteja no caminho certo):

```
<?php 
  if(file_exists("bd/colaboradores.json")){

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

    $arquivo = file_get_contents('bd/colaboradores.json');
    $json = json_decode($arquivo);

    foreach($json as $registro):
        if($registro->codigo == $_GET['id']){

          $novos_dados = array($registro->nome = $nome,
            $registro->email = $email,
            $registro->telefone = $telefone
          );

        }
    endforeach;
  }else{
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
?>
```

Comment: json decode e faz um foreach e passa no update

Answer (score 0):

Respostas sobre a dúvida com json

```
public function update(Request $request){

       $dados = Model::find($request->get('id'));

       foreach(json_decode($request->json) as $dado){
          $dados->nome -> $dado['nome']; // assim continua faz o teste e me retorna
       }

       $dados->save();
}
```

Comment: olha, sou iniciante e nao sei bem como usar, mas qundo coloquei essa função deu um erro no "public". Olhe: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file`. vou deixar meu html la na pergunta, pra ficar melhor de entender como está.

Comment: @SaMuK posta na pergunta o dd($request->all());

Comment: Desculpa, nao entendi Lucas. Oque eu devo passar como parametro? E oque é esse Model? Eu tentei passar o Json diretamente, ao inves de usar o request e ter que usar ma function, mas nao entendi bem.

Comment: Vou deixar como estava fazendo, na pergunta... (está errado... nao funciona, mas é so pra vc entender como estava minha linha de raciocinio)

Comment: @SaMuK por que você armazena arquivos amigo? Lamento não consigo te ajudar ta muito confuso sua dúvida e seu código.